# ファイル名に含まれるアンダーバー以降の数字の連続を削除したい

Tags: shellscript, sed

```
aaa01.txt
bbb01.txt
```

というファイルのあるフォルダで

```
find ./ -type f | sed 'p;s/01/02/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

とやると、

```
aaa02.txt
bbb02.txt
```

となります。

これを応用して

```
aaa_0101.txt
bbb_2201.txt
```

を

```
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
```

のようにするには、`xargs`のコマンドをどう変更したらよいですか？

よろしくお願い致します

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed の部分を変更して次のように実行します。

```
find ./ -type f | sed 'p; s/_[0-9]*\././' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Comment: 希望通りに動作しました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

便乗失礼します。
AB1111_あいうえお_1_1.pdf
AB2222_かきくけこ_1_1.pdf
・
・
を
AB1111.pdf
AB2222.pdf
に変更する（アンダーバー以降を削除）するにはこちらのコードは使えませんでした。
数字ではなく文字列だからでしょうか？
このように変更するには、sedの部分をどのように変更すればよろしいでしょうか？

よろしければご教示ください。

Comment: 当サイトはスレッド式の掲示板とは違うため、こちらの投稿は [新しい質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) として投稿してみてください。 / "質問に対する回答" になっていないため、削除される可能性があります。